# Internationalization in Spring Oauth exception messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to have Spring Oauth2 error messages localized? Especially the error messages for InvalidGrantException and UsernameNotFoundException.

Comment: I suspect not in the case of the `InvalidGrantException`. The `UsernameNotFoundException` is part of Spring Security core, so it might have some i18n. It might all depend on where you want to localize them - if it's in log files you are probably out of luck.

Comment: @DaveSyer I'm open to suggestions. If I could localize them at the DB level I'm open to that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the DB". Who is going to consume your localized data?

Comment: @DaveSyer DB as in database for localization abstraction. The consumers of my data are end users. Which in that case, I want to ensure that I offer localized translated text in the event of error.

Comment: A user wouldn't normally see security exception messages. What is the scenario exactly?

Comment: @DaveSyer I implemented a custom grant type in Spring Oauth that utilizes limited number of logins attempts (6 tries). When the 6 tries are exceeded, the error response is states the account is locked and how many minutes remaining before the user retries.

Comment: Yes, but it's not the user per se interacting with the token endpoint is it? There must be an app sending the requests (and if it's a custom grant type it must be a custom app), so it can do the localization I suppose.

Comment: @DaveSyer OK but, any advice on how I could localize this feature?

Comment: @DaveSyer can we do it with use of ControllerAdvice in spring, where we can caught Oauth exception & return localize message ?

Comment: On the client you mean? I guess that would work as long as you always use a controller to access the remote resource.

Comment: @DaveSyer  I am confused, are you saying I should do localization from the client rather than relying on the provider? Meaning if the provider sends a http error response, the client should capture it and localize accordingly.

Comment: I guess it depends on your client. It might be easier to make modifications there, especially given that the server doesn't naturally know the right locale. On the server you could use controller advice but you might have to duplicate some of the native error handling code.

Comment: @DaveSyer regarding your original assumption, it is the user interacting with the endpoint. The custom granter I've setup is similar to the passwordGrant type. So essentially, once the user provides their username and password and if the multiple tries are exceeded, I wanted a way to be interactive when the user tries to login. Also, you mentioned "server doesn't naturally know the right locale". I send the locale from the client website to the server API , in the header so there's a way.

Comment: I don't think a user should be interacting with the token endpoint. If you use a Spring on the client then you can deal with the exception as indicated (and other frameworks have other mechanisms). Maybe I don't understand the details of your custom grant, but if I were you I would go with standard auth code protocol or something very similar. If you do then  you can deal with the l10n in the client app. Even if your grant type is more off the wall your client code must be able to protect the user, I would have thought.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too late, but gonna leave my answer here so maybe someone else interested.

As far as I know, there is no builtin internationalization feature in Spring OAuth2 (please correct me if I am wrong). However, Spring lets us to extends the default implementations to get it up. There are 2 possible approaches for this I'd guess:

**1. Backend**

Internationalize your error messages on your server and return them to the API. This requires locale resolving (e.g. header locale resolving)

**2. Backend + Frontend**

Attach additional error codes to your response and the frontend need to map them into localized message.

The idea is to implement a custom TokenGranter and translate an AuthenticationException into your own exception (e.g. InvalidGrantException) on authenticating.

Example below creates different error codes for different types of invalid_grant **(appoache #2)**:

```
    public class CustomTokenGranter extends AbstractTokenGranter {

        private static final String ERROR_CODE_KEY = "error_code";

        @Override
        protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {
            try {
                ....
                authenticationManager.authenticate(...);
            } catch (AccountStatusException ase) {
                mapAndThrow(ase);
            } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
                InvalidGrantException ige = new InvalidGrantException("Bad credentials");
                ige.addAdditionalInformation(ERROR_CODE_KEY, "01234");
                throw ige;
            }
        }


        private void mapAndThrow(AccountStatusException ase) {
            InvalidGrantException ige = new InvalidGrantException(ase.getMessage());
            if (ase instanceof DisabledException) {
                ige.addAdditionalInformation(ERROR_CODE_KEY, "01235");
            } else if (ase instanceof LockedException) {
                ige.addAdditionalInformation(ERROR_CODE_KEY, "01236");
            } else if (ase instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
                ige.addAdditionalInformation(ERROR_CODE_KEY, "01237");
            }
            // More goes here
            throw ige;
        }
    }
```

Register the custom token granter to your authorization server:

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenGranter(new CustomTokenGranter (...));
    }
}
```

Example response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "User is disabled",
    "error_code": "01235"
}
```

If you want to take to **approach #1**, you can do something similar to the approach #2 and resolve your locale by obtaining the servlet request from RequestContextHolder:

```
RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
if (requestAttributes != null && requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
    HttpServletRequest sRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
    Locale locale = sRequest.getLocale(); ...
    // Resolve your error messages here from above obtained locale
}
```